# Adding a link to download the original image to a view

Tags: views, theming, media

I would like to add at the end of the description a link like saying "Download HiRes Image" at the end of the caption of the image in this view, but I don't know how. I did try with the module DownloadFile but there is no documentation about it.

http://www.nellens.com/home/photos-full/segunda-serie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DownloadFile](https://drupal.org/project/download_file) module, which allows you to download Files or Images, and it's usable in views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still looking for a way to insert the link, the problem is that I don't see the documentation about how to do it, thanks again.

Comment: You need to add the field to your views (your image), and choose the correct display (one added by the DownloadFile module).

Comment: I just got how to do it, now I have the problem that all my images are in one field of "image" for an easy drag and drop manipulation, but anyway your answer solved my problem for that side, thanks.